# HelixViewport3d Ctrl + C

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, copy-paste, helix-3d-toolkit

I am using HelixToolkit.Wpf in a WPF / .Net Framework 4.7.2 application. I am trying to make a copy-paste functionality. To achive it, I have the following code in my xaml file:

```
<KeyBinding Key="C" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding CopyCommand}" />
<KeyBinding Key="V" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding PasteCommand}" />
```

The `PasteCommand` is called as expected, but the `CopyCommand` is not.

When profiling the app, I can see that large MemoryStreams are created when I type Ctrl+C on the keyboard and I can see that the CPU is spending a lot of time in `HelixToolkit.Wpf.HelixViewport3D.Copy()`. I think it is copying the screen view as a bitmap or something like that.

It looks to me like the "Ctrl+C" is already pre-assigned behind the scenes, but I cannot find any documentation about it.

***How would you overwrite this key binding to call my own copy code?***

Comment: The best and fastest way to learn it is that ask them directly i believe. Can you ask [here](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/issues) also. Open an issue and ask, they will help asap.

Comment: @Alp that was a really good idea. I posted the question here https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/issues/1740 Lets see if they can help me.